# How does Solr scale function works?

Tags: solr

Solr documentation [says](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#scale) that the scale function:

> scales values of the function x such that they fall between minTarget
>   and maxTarget inclusive.

As an example it says:

> scale(x,1,2) all values will be between 1 and 2 inclusive.

My question is, how?
If I give this function the number 78.3 and try to scale it between 1 and 2, how it translates into a 1 to 2 format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will go through all the documents in your index (if I [read the source](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/5e5fd662575105de88d8514b426bccdcb4c76948/lucene/queries/src/java/org/apache/lucene/queries/function/valuesource/ScaleFloatFunction.java) correctly, it works with the complete set of documents and not the current result set), find the minimum and maxiumum values, then scale the value in each document when returning it to be between the two provided numbers.

So if you have documents with 0, 5, 10 and invokes `scale(x, 1, 2)`, you should get `1`, `1.5` and `2` back.

The actual implementation from the source:

```
return (vals.floatVal(doc) - minSource) * scale + min;
```